# Writing MD5 (SALTED) password cracker

Tags: python, python-2.7, md5, password-encryption

I'm working on an assignment where I have to write a password cracker, to crack a password of which I have found the hashed value while compromising a system (.htpasswd) file on a web server.

I've written the program and it works fine with simple and basic MD5 hashes, but the one I will be using is Salted MD5 hash.

I've asked for assistance from my lecturer and he provided this:

> Import module from passlib.hash import apr_md5_crypt 
>   use this function apr_md5_ crypt.encrypt(password, salt=salt) 
>   where the password is the word from RockYou and salt is the value from the developer's hash value. This should help you out.

I've added this in my program but it's still not picking the password from a wordlist that contains the password.

The aim is to make my code work, not to find the password (I managed to get it in a previous stage using John The Ripper).

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

#Importing algorithm
import md5
import hashlib
import passlib.hash
#Importing the algorithm for the hashed SALT
from passlib.hash import apr_md5_crypt

#The password is 1qa2ws3ed
#The SALT value is Wv63/0xM

counter = 1

pass_in = raw_input("Please enter MD5 Hash: ")
pwfile = raw_input("please enter the wordlist file name: ")

#Opening the file to make sure the path is correct prior commencing to crack the password
try:
   pwfile = open(pwfile, "r")
except:
   print "\nFile Not found."
   quit()
for password in pwfile:
   filemd5 = apr_md5_crypt.encrypt('1qa2ws3ed', salt='Wv63/0xM')
   md5.new(password.strip()).hexdigest()
   print "Trying password number %d: %s " % (counter, password.strip())

   counter += 1

   if pass_in == filemd5:
       print "\nMatch Found. \nPassword is: %s" % password
       break

else: print "\nPassword Not Found."
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images. In order to help you, people may need to copy your code to execute it, and it's not quite easy to accomplish using an image. modify your question, including the code as text.

Comment: It should be immediately obvious what the problem is if you just add a `print(filemd5)` in your loop.

Comment: @hoefling: I'm really sorry about that, as I said I just signed up an hour ago and I thought this will be easier to view my code.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, have you tried it? What did it print?

Comment: (I have cut your "long story short" a bit shorter but I noticed it is lacking a clear problem statement. Obviously, it does not work -- so no need to add that -- but *what* does not work? What happens when you run this?)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I added what you have said it printed the exact hash from the .htpasswd file $apr1$Wv63/0xM$6hoeCDM.YzSITNZYFf6Bd/

Comment: Did it print only that and nothing else? It's in the loop, right? It should print many different values, shouldn't it?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. It seems your problem is something else. Try adding `password = password.rstrip('\r\n')` at the top of your loop.

Comment: Trying password number 324: 1q2w3e45t6y7u8i
$apr1$Wv63/0xM$6hoeCDM.YzSITNZYFf6Bd/